# get list of active system.out printstreams

Tags: java, system.out, printstream

I was trying to use System.out.println to help with debugging and I found that it wasn't printing to the console. On inspection I found that my program had created 4 output consoles ( one for Java DB processes, one for the DB server, one for debugging the program, and one for program output ). I found my expected println in an unexpected console - the DB server output.
I would like to get a handle on these outputs. I expected the System class to have a list field of active output consoles ( printstreams ), something like :

```
 ArrayList<PrintStream> getActivePrintOutputs()
```

But I don't see one. How do I get them?

Answer (score 1):

Normally you have only one active `System.out` output stream, so there is no reason for the system to maintain a list.

If you want to trace all the PrintStreams created you can use instrumentation to track their creation, or put a break point in the constructor for the class and debug your program.

NOTE: Is is normal for a program to create multiple logs files for different purposes and these might be the PrintStreams you are thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

`System` has no concept of multiple output streams beyond those specified by `out` and `err`, and you can access those by just referencing `System.out` and `System.err` respectively.

If there are other consoles or output streams being used, they must have been created by other points in your code (or other points in a library's code that you're using.)